# How to override result of hasMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Imagine I have a couple of simple objects like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Post");
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}
```

We'll say the `\App\Post` object has an database column called `jsondata` which contains JSON-encoded data. When I want to display the user's posts in a view with that column decoded, I need to do this in the controller:

```
$posts = Auth::user()->posts()->get();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->jsondata = json_decode($post->jsondata);
}
return view("user.show", ["posts"=>$posts]);
```

Is there a way to avoid that `foreach` loop in my controller and do the JSON decoding at a lower level?

I'm sure I could do this in `App\User::posts()` but that doesn't help other places where I need to display the decoded data. I tried defining `App\Post::get()` to override the parent method, but it doesn't work because `hasMany()` doesn't seem to return an instance of the model at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alessandro's answer seemed like the best one; it pointed me to the Laravel documentation on accessors and mutators. But, near the bottom of the page is an even easier method: [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

In typical Laravel fashion, they don't actually list all the types you can cast to, but they do mention being able to cast a JSON-formatted database column to an array. A little poking through [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2809) and it turns out you can do the same with an object. So my answer, added to the `App\Post` controller, is this:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = ["jsondata"=>"object"];
```

This automatically does the decode and makes the raw data available. As a bonus, it automatically does a JSON encode when saving!

Comment: Should be better or not. It depends if you want to keep also the encoded data attribute or not. Laravel provides you many many methods to do the same things, there isn't always a best one, but there are good or bad approaches to problems

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in different places/ways, but I would suggest to use an append for this property in your model if you want this data is always decoded everywhere and every time you retrieve a Post model, or simply a mutator.

see https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators

In your model you can define:

```
protected $appends = [
    'name_of_property'
];

// calculated / mutated field
public function getNameOfPropertyAttribute()
{
    return jsondecode($this->jsondata);
}
```

You then can always access this property with:

$post->name_of_property

Note the conversion from CamelCase to snake_case and the conversion from getNameOfPropertyAttribute > name_of_property. By default you need to respect this convention to get it working automagically.

You can substitute the name_of_property and NameOfProperty with what you want accordingly.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. It pointed me to an even better solution.